# Proving that the characteristic function is uniformly continous.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, uniform-continuity

I am trying to prove that the characteristic function is uniformly continuous.

I understand how to get to this bound:

[image]

And I would like to find the $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$  but I am used to having $|f(x) -f(c)|$ instead of $|f(x+h) - f(x)|$ when doing uniform continuous proofs.
Also $X$ is a random variable and I am unsure how to proceed.

Could I see how one would terminate this proof by finding the correct $\delta$?

Answer (score 13):

If $E(X)$ is finite, the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372337/inequality-involving-complex-exponential) $|e^{ihx}-1|\le |hx|$ gets you uniform continuity right away: $$|\varphi(t+h)-\varphi(t)|\le\int|hx|dF_X(x)=|h|E(|X|)\;.$$

If $X$ is not integrable,  you've already found an upper bound that is free of $t$, so it suffices to show that $$\lim_{h\to0}\int|e^{ihx}-1|dF_X(x)=0\;,\tag1$$
 since (1) then implies that for every $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $\delta>0$ such that $\int|e^{ihx}-1|dF_X(x)<\varepsilon$ whenever $|h|<\delta$. To show (1), you can use the 'sequence' approach: argue that $\int|e^{ih_nx}-1|dF_X(x)\to0$ whenever $h_n$ is a sequence tending to zero; this follows from the bounded convergence theorem.