# Characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a measurable space and $X:\Omega \to
> > \mathbb{R}$ a random variable.
>
> Assuming $E[|X|]<\infty$, prove that $\psi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]$ is absolutely continuous.
>
> [Hint: first, prove that $|\psi_X(t+h)-\psi_X(t)|\leq E[|e^{ihX}-1|]$
>   for every $t, h \in \mathbb{R}$]

I had no problem proving the statement in the hint, but I'm having a difficult time to prove that: $$\forall\epsilon>0 ,\exists\delta>0\ \text{with}$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(b_k-a_k)<\delta \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n}E[|e^{i(b_k-a_k)X}-1|]<\epsilon, $$

where $(a_1, b_1), ...,(a_n, b_n)$ are disjoint intervals, which is what I think I'm supposed to do.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to prove *absolute* continuity or *uniform* continuity of the CF? For uniform continuity, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247373/proving-that-the-characteristic-function-is-uniformly-continous

Comment: @grand_chat ??? If you look at the details of what the OP says he's trying to do it's clear he means absolute continuity.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Understood, but you just provided a counterexample to absolute continuity.

Comment: sorry guys, I got mixed up with the definition of absolute continuity, already edited it

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, the condition $E[|X|]<\infty$ was not in the material from which I took the question. But now I'm convinced it's necessary, already edited it again. Thanks

Comment: See new version of the answer. This morning I thought the author just left out a hypothesis; I now think he simply screwed up.

Answer (score 5):

There is something fishy about the problem.

The OP says that in the original source the problem was to prove that the characteristic function of *any* random variable is absolutely continuous. This is false; it's easy to give an example of a nowhere-differentiable characteristic function, as below.

As I pointed out this morning, if we assume that $\Bbb E[|X|]<\infty$ then it's easy to show that the characteristic function is absolutely continuous (hint: $|e^{it}-1|\le |t|$ for $t\in\Bbb R$). But I must have been asleep, suggesting that without noticing that that's a very curious problem, since it's also easy to show that $\Bbb E[|X|]<\infty$ implies that the characteristic function is continuously differentiable (with bounded derivative)!

I can't think of a "natural" "probabilistic" condition that implies the characteristic function is absolutely continuous without also implying that it is continuously differentiable. Since $$\sup_{\delta_j>0,\,\sum\delta_j=\delta}\sum\left|e^{i\delta_jt}-1\right|=\delta|t|$$it seems there is *no* condition weaker than $\Bbb E[|X|]<\infty$ such that *it is possible to use the hint given to show that* the characteristic function is absolutely continuous.

---

A simple although not quite self-contained counterexample to the OP as originally stated, without the assumption on the first moment. It's easy to construct a discrete $X$ so that $$\psi_X(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}e^{2\pi i 4^nt}.$$That's a classic example of a nowhere-differentiable function.

Comment: Sorry, I really got mixed up with definition, already edited it