# Is this proof of convergence is distribution of product of random variables correct?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, weak-convergence

Given that $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$ prove that $X_nY_n \Rightarrow XY$, if both $\{X_n, Y_n\}; \{X,Y\}$ are independent.

This is my attempt:

I aim to prove
\begin{align}
\Bbb E_{X_n Y_n}(e^{itX_n Y_n}) = \Bbb E_{XY}(e^{itXY}) \forall t\in \Bbb R \; \;  \text{(Because by [Levy's continuity theorem][1] the statement will follow)} \\
\end{align}
Now, Taking limit $n \to \infty$ on LHS and using

1. Tower Property of Expectation
2. Dominated Convergence Theorem
3. using Portmanteau lemma (ii) ([as Characteristic function is
   uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247373/proving-that-the-characteristic-function-is-uniformly-continous))
4. Independence

, we have 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E_{X_n Y_n}(e^{itX_n Y_n}) \overset{(1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E_{Y_n} \Bbb E_{X_n|Y_n}(e^{itX_nY_n}) \\ \overset{(4)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E_{Y_n} \Bbb E_{X_n}(e^{itX_nY_n}) \overset{(2)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E_{Y_n} \Bbb \lim_{n \to \infty} E_{X_n}(e^{itX_nY_n}) \\ \overset{(3)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Bbb E_{Y_n}  \Bbb E_{X}(e^{itXY_n}) \overset{(3)} =  \Bbb E_{Y}  \Bbb E_{X}(e^{itXY}) \overset{(1)} =  \Bbb E_{X Y}(e^{itX Y}) $

Is my proof correct? Thank you!

Edited to reflect d.k.o's comments:
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Characteristic_function_of_product_of_random_variables), it is stated that the product of two independent random variables $Z = XY$ has the following characteristic function:

\begin{align}
\varphi_Z(t) & =\operatorname{E}(e^{itX Y}) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \operatorname{E}_{X Y \mid Y} (e^{itX Y} \mid Y)) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \operatorname{E}_{X \mid Y} (e^{itX Y} \mid Y)) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \varphi_X(tY))
\end{align}

Therefore, we have the characteristic function of $Z_n = X_nY_n$ as $\varphi_{Z_n}(t) = \operatorname{E}_{Y_n} ( \varphi_{X_n}(tY_n)) = \operatorname{E}_{Y_n} ( \operatorname{E}_{X_n} (e^{itX_nY_n})) $.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}_{Y_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_n}\ldots$?

Comment: @d.k.o. By $\Bbb E_{Y_n} \Bbb E_{X_n} (.)$, I meant, first the expectation wrt  $X_n$ and later wrt $Y_n$. I was trying to follow the steps mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Expectation_of_product_of_random_variables

Comment: @d.k.o. Kindly let me know if it is not correct.

Comment: Unlike the product of random variables the exponent of that product cannot be decomposed into the product of exponents. Also in your case $\mathbb{E}_{Y_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_n\mid Y_n}\ldots \ne \mathbb{E}_{Y_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_n}\ldots$

Comment: @d.k.o. - Thanks for pointing out the error. The right expression would be \begin{align} \varphi_Z(t) & =\operatorname{E}(e^{itX Y}) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \operatorname{E}_{X Y \mid Y} (e^{itX Y} \mid Y)) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \operatorname{E}_{X \mid Y} (e^{itX Y} \mid Y)) 
\\ & = \operatorname{E}_Y ( \varphi_X(tY))
\end{align}

Comment: @d.k.o. It looks like in general, $\mathbb{E}_{Y_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_n\mid Y_n}\ldots \ne \mathbb{E}_{Y_n}\mathbb{E}_{X_n}\ldots$ but, for independent random variables, it looks like the equality holds. I edited my question to give more details about this.

Answer (score 1):

By independence $(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow{d}(X,Y)$ because
$$
\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}(sX_n+tY_n)}=\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}sX_n}\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}tY_n}\to\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}sX}\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}tY}=\mathsf{E}e^{\mathbf{i}(sX+tY)}
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Then use the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Convergence_in_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a proof for this that does not invoke Levy's theorem. First, by independence you have: $$\mathbb{P}[X_n \leq x, Y_n \leq y] = \mathbb{P}[X_n \leq x]\mathbb{P}[Y_n \leq y] \overset{d}{\to} \mathbb{P}[X \leq x]\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x, Y \leq y]$$ This proves $(X_n, Y_n) \overset{d}{\to} (X,Y)$. Now write $g(X_n, Y_n) = X_nY_n$ and $g(X,Y) = XY$. You can now invoke continuous mapping theorem and write $$(X_n, Y_n) \overset{d}{\to} (X,Y) \implies g(X_n,Y_n) \overset{d}{\to} g(X,Y) \implies X_nY_n \overset{d}{\to} XY$$ establishing the result.