# Characteristic function and continuity in probability

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

How can I prove that this characteristic function is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

$$\Phi_X(t)=\sum e^{itx_k}P(X=x_k)$$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247373/proving-that-the-characteristic-function-is-uniformly-continous) is the equivalent for a continuous random variable. (Well, technically it's applicable in general, due to the $dF_X(x)$ formalism.)

Comment: I cannot use the continuous random variable approach since they use the dominated convergence theorem while here i have a sums approach to the variable X

Comment: I understand; the idea was to adapt it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to adapt it using the continuous random variables since its all I see online but I had a lot of technical problems

Comment: Fair enough. If you edit such efforts into your question, we can give more useful help.

Comment: If you merely want to improve your question in the future, leave it as is until you actually improve it. If you have realized that you want to ask a somewhat different question, leave it as it is and ask a new question instead (and maybe link to it here). If you feel unsure about what to do *and* feel like asking this question doesn’t make much sense to begin with *and* the answers already given don’t actually answer the question you have asked, delete it – you may undelete it later. But never ever vandalize your question by removing its contents in edits. I have rolled your edit back.

Comment: I'm planning to edit the entire exercice with the solutions I've found so far that I'm sure of by browsing this site and making it easier to see the whole demonstrations for everyone. The answers provided under my question were very helpful and quite the correct logical demonstrations.

Comment: @math777 Please don't vandalize the question after it has been answered. You are free to ask new question (if it's different) and referrence them as needed.

Comment: Please don't vandalise a question which has answers - by all means edit it so that it is a better question. But don't take away from the effort others have made to help you, and don't forget that other people may have the same issue you already had - part of the point of the site is to help future users too.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an $\epsilon>0$ and choose $K$ such that $\sum_{|k| > K} P[X=x_k] < {1\over 2} \epsilon$.

Each $t \mapsto e^{it x_k}$ is Lipschitz with rank $|x_k|$ hence uniformly continuous.

The (finite) sum of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Hence $g(t)= \sum_{|k| \le K} e^{it x_k} P[X=x_k] $ is uniformly continuous.

Pick some $\delta$ such that if $|s-t| < \delta $ then $|g(t)-g(s)| < {1\over 2} \epsilon$.

Then $|\Phi_X(t)-\Phi_X(s)| \le |g(t)-g(s)| + \sum_{|k| > K} P[X=x_k] < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, would you mind explaining the idea behind this $$\sum_{|k| > K} P[X=x_k] < {1\over 2} \epsilon$$.

Comment: @math777 It's to ensure each of two terms is each of modulus less than $\epsilon/2$; their sum is then of modulus less than $\epsilon$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: As far as I know, the sum of all probabilities add up to 1 so I got confused in the $${1\over 2} \epsilon$$.

Comment: The sum of the probabilities is one so we have $\lim_{K \to 0} \sum_{|k| > K} P[X=x_k] = 0$.

Comment: This is why I was struggling with the demonstration, I had no idea that this limit converges to zero. I assume the idea to take the absolute value of k instead of k is due to us proving the continuous uniformity in R ?

Comment: No, it is because I don't know if $k$ can be negative in your formula ($x_{-1}$ may have a non zero probability for all I know).

Comment: Oh I see, well k is positive. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: In that case you can just use $k>K$, etc. In general, if $\sum_k a_k $ converges  we have that the 'tail' $\sum_{k>K} a_k \to 0$ (as $K \to \infty$).

Comment: @copper.hat thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm e}$The approach with the dominated convergence theorem still works since you can write $\Phi_X(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}\e^{itx}\,\mu(dx)$, where $\mu = X_*\mathbb P$ is the pushforward measure of $\mu$. There is nothing pathological about having a discrete random variable that changes the proof.

Concretely, let $\varepsilon > 0$ and write
\begin{align*}
|\Phi_X(t+h)-\Phi_X(t)| &= \bigg|\int_{\mathbb R}\e^{itx}[\e^{ihx}-1]\,\mu(dx)\bigg| \\
&\le \int_{\mathbb R}|\e^{ihx}-1|\,\mu(dx) \qquad\text{(a bound independent of $t$)}.
\end{align*}
Now, for each $x\in\mathbb R$ (in particular, for $\mu$-a.e $x$), we have $|\e^{ihx}-1|\le 2\in L^1(\mathbb R,\mathrm{Borel},\mu)$, and $|\e^{ihx}-1|\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. By the dominated (or merely bounded) convergence theorem in the measure space $(\mathbb R,\mathrm{Borel},\mu)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ so that if $|h| < \delta$, then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}|\e^{ihx}-1|\,\mu(dx)<\varepsilon,
$$
so whenever $|h|<\delta$, we have $|\Phi_X(t+h)-\Phi_X(t)| < \varepsilon$. As the $\delta$ we found is independent of $t$, $\Phi_X$ is thus uniformly continuous.

---

You can also prove this directly as follows:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and choose $K$ so large that $\sum_{k>K}P(X=x_k) < \varepsilon/4$ (which is possible because $\sum P(X=x_k) = 1$, in particular, $\sum P(X=x_k)$ converges). Note that $K$ is independent of $t$ (we have not even mentioned $t$ yet). Write as before,
\begin{align*}
|\Phi_X(t+h)-\Phi_X(t)| &= \bigg|\sum\e^{it x_k}[\e^{ihx_k}-1]P(X=x_k)\bigg|\\
&\le \sum |[\e^{ihx_k}-1]P(X=x_k)|\\
&= \sum_{k\le K}|[\e^{ihx_k}-1]P(X=x_k)| + \sum_{k>K}|[\e^{ihx_k}-1]P(X=x_k)|\\
&\le \sum_{k\le K}|\e^{ihx_k}-1| + 2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{4}.
\end{align*}
Now choose $\delta$ so small so that if $|h|<\delta$, then $|\e^{ihx_k}-1| < \varepsilon/2(K+1)$ (note how we can choose $\delta$ independently of $t$). Thus, whenever $|h|<\delta$, we have
$$
|\Phi_X(t+h)-\Phi_X(t)| < (K+1)\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2(K+1)} + 2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{4} = \varepsilon.
$$

Comment: Thank you, of course we can write the function that way , the problem I have isn't proving that it is uniformly continuous but rather using the sums in proving so.

Comment: @math777: I updated my answer with a direct proof. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Amazing, thank you a lot. I will go ahead now and try to comprehend your reasoning, it is indeed very helpful

Comment: i ve just redid your proof and would u mind explaining why you picked this $$|\e^{ihx_k}-1| < \varepsilon/2(2K+1)$$ . Shouldnt we choose K+1 since the sum goes from zero to K therefore once we sum 1 from zero to K it should give us K+1 and then we are left with $$ \varepsilon/2$$

Comment: @math777: I just edited my answer to reflect that we are working with $k\ge 0$. In my original post, I assumed that the range of summation was over all integers $k$, rather than all nonnegative integers. If $k\ge 0$, then we choose $K+1$, as you noted.

Comment: is it not obligated to give a value to $$\delta$$ ?

Comment: I have thought of using $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {2 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{K} |hx_k|}$ , would it be appropriate to do so?

Comment: @math777: If you believe that the functions $f_k(h)\equiv \mathrm{e}^{ihx_k}-1$ are continuous and $f_k(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$, then it is not really necessary to find an explicit value of $\delta$. Simply note the existence of such $\delta_k$ so that $|\mathrm{e}^{ihx_k}-1|<\varepsilon/2(K+1)$ for each $k=0,\dots,K$, and take $\delta$ to be the minimum of these $\delta_k$. If you want to name an explicit value of $\delta$, you will have to estimate the terms $|\mathrm{e}^{ihx_k}-1|$. In any case, $\delta$ cannot depend on $h$, so the value of $\delta$ you quoted me doesn't make sense yet.

Comment: @math777: Also, if my answer or the other answer to your question have helped you, it is polite to click the "up" arrow next to the answers and to accept one or the other if one answered your question